# Querying OpenStreetMap API for map features

Tags: java, android, api, openstreetmap

I am developing an application which needs to query OpenStreetMap API for 
various map features (mostly road type) and I don't need to use maps at all.

What would be the best way to retrieve such information? Is there any specific 
OSM API or an Android library I should focus on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). For constructing queries you can also use the [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) frontend.

Don't use the [main API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) because it is for *editing* only. Also it is slower and less powerfull than Overpass API.